# Tokenizing your data in spring boot with Protegrity

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

In my project I have a Spring Boot app which consumes the data from Az Event hub and pushes it to MSSQL db. It is a simple project. But now I have been asked to do tokenization of the incoming payload before pushing onto db. They have asked me to do it with Protegrity. But till now I have not found a single way for this. Now my concern is

1. Is it possible to tokenize data in Spring boot at all? Or with Protegrity? If yes, please help me on this.
2. Is there any other way to tokenize in Azure so that my app would not have to worry about it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to tokenize the data with Protegrity in Azure.

- Protegrity currently supports protection/unprotection via external **User Defined Functions (UDF)** and **Protegrity SQL Gateway** is in the roadmap.
- We can use SQL Server on Azure VM to support external UDF and integrate it with Protegrity engine where the query is pushed down to Azure Synapse Analytics using the linked server created in the SQL Synapse Pool.

Here are some approaches that helps in the invoking of external UDF and then detokenizing it in Azure Synapse SQL Pool:

1. Power M Query to invoke a Rest API
2. SQL Server Gateway - Linked Server between SQL Server and Synapse SQL Pool
3. SQL Server Gateway – Polybase

Reference - [Tokenization](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-architecture-blog/data-analytics-solution-tokenization-with-external-tokenization/ba-p/2821038)